# Which apps do these menu bar icons belong to?

Tags: applications, icon, menu-bar

I've seen a few of these icons before, such as the cursive "L"; however, I can't figure out which applications they belong to.

[image: seven unknown menu bar icons]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From left to right…

- [RescueTime](https://www.rescuetime.com)
- [Divvy](http://mizage.com)
- [Clusters](http://clustersapp.com)
- [LittleIpsum](https://itunes.apple.com/gb/app/littleipsum/id405772121?mt=12)
- [LogMeIn](https://secure.logmein.com)
- OS X Screen Sharing
- OS X Messages/iChat